# Way to lower the mattress inside a cot gracefully

Tags: furniture

I'm having a hard time transferring my son to his cot without waking him - the moment I lower him into the cot, he wakes up.

If I can raise the mattress inside the cot, and then lower it slowly once he is on the mattress, I figured it would be a lot easier.

Do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this in an easy enough way?

Comment: Parental wisdom: That type of thing leads to overly-sensitive sleep habits. Better that your child (barring any cognitive challenges) learn to go to sleep on his own. Also bad: keeping the house perfectly quiet during naps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: This would be a better fit over on [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: If the OP wants a hydraulic platform or a screw thread system similar to a car jack to lift the mattress would that be on topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been there, and I sympathize (survived 3...)

Does your cot have a side that lowers? That helps.

It does get better with practice...

One thing that may help is to cuddle them with a blanket and lay them down **with** the blanket - often the colder bedding is the trigger to wake them...

The other thing we did was to use a sheepskin for them to lay on - very good for temperature - apologies to any if that is a "left-field" solution...

Aslo we never had "silent mode" in the house, even if the kids were having a lunchtime nap, it was hoover as normal etc - they soon slept through it...